# How to Merge two different Git repositories?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

I have two Github repositories. One repository is on the remote server and another on the local server. Both of them have different commit histories of different files and folders. Now I wanted to merge both of them so that I can have both of them on the remote server as one single repository. Please help!

I have looked for various solutions suggesting as: reset the head of the local repository and then pull the remote repository on the same directory but it doesn't seem to be working:

git reset --soft head ~CommitSHA (First commit of the local repo)

git pull ~giturlofremoterepo (Pulling remote repo in the same directory)

Comment: Do you want to keep the codebase at a single place i.e. the remote server or merge the actual changelist for both into a single master?

Comment: @nitishagar Yes, I want to keep the codebase at a single place i.e. remote server.

Answer (score 14):

In a nutshell you can checkout one repository, add a remote to the second, rebase the second on top of the first and push the result to your new single remote repository:

Clone the first repository and add a remote to the second

```
git clone https://first.repo
git remote add second https://second.repo
```

Fetch the second and check its master branch out to a local branch `second`

```
git fetch second
git checkout second/master
git checkout -b second
```

Rebase the master branch of the second repository on top of the master branch of the first. Resolve any potential conflict along the way.

```
git rebase master second
```

Push to a new upstream repository

```
git push -u ...
```

This results in the two commit histories being concatenated one after each other.

Answer (score 6):

Create a new git repository and initialize with a new README file.

```
$ mkdir merged_repo
$ cd merged_repo
$ git init 
$ touch README.md
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initialize new repo"
```

Add the first remote repository

```
$ git remote add -f first_repo `link_to_first_repo`
$ git merge --allow-unrelated-histories first_repo/master
```

Create a sub directory and move all first_repo files to it.

```
$ mkdir first_repo
$ mv * first_repo/
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Move first_repo files to first_repo directory"
```

Add the second remote repository

```
$ git remote add -f second_repo `link_to_second_repo`
$ git merge --allow-unrelated-histories second_repo/master
```

Fix any merge conflicts and complete the merge as follows

```
$ git merge --continue
```