# Git - Replacing a Laravel installation with a new version

Tags: laravel, bitbucket

I have a Laravel installation on Digital Ocean being pulled from Bitbucket. Recently I created a new local Laravel updated version of the site in a new repository. I would now like to replace the version that is on Digital Ocean. 
Is there an easy way of achieving this rather than deleting the original and pulling the updated one from a new repo on Bitbucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a version tracking related question than it is a laravel question. The answer depends on the versioning system you use, for now I assume Git.

You could do a manual copy/paste:
- checkout original repository
- delete all files and folders
- now copy the files from your new repository into the empty repository
- commit and push
- pull updates code on your server.

This is not super elegant, since you basically forget about any commits you made in your new repository. For more elegant solutions, search for `git merge 2 repositories`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56597484/9258054 for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are several posible solutions the one I use and like the most is a tool called https://deployer.org where you can define your repository and the commands to execute when you deploy. It also keeps versions in case you need to rollback.