# Manually merge files after rebase

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I'm having my main project `A` from which I copied some files and set up a project `A_Zero`.

Meanwhile `A_Zero` is working well and I'm thinking of merging it back into Project `A`.

The files and folder structure is different. Some files still basically do the same but I got rid of a lot of the code and the files sill show similarities.

I would like to manually merge the files, but this won't happen. A lot of the files would go to the Sub-Directory PoM, but right now they are still in the top-folder. If I use `git mv` I get:

```
$ git mv ArangoUtils.py PoM/ArangoUtils.py 
fatal: not under version control, source=ArangoUtils.py, destination=PoM/ArangoUtils.py
```

`git add` won't solve it either:

```
$ git add ArangoUtils.py 
$ git mv ArangoUtils.py PoM
fatal: destination exists, source=ArangoUtils.py, destination=PoM/ArangoUtils.py
```

There's quite a bunch of these files, the rebase certainly did something, but still all files are where they were and I still have to figure out how to merge them. The references git sets up are correct, how would I let git execute the merge of them?

```
$ git rebase --continue
Applying: first commit in submodule
Applying: geth
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
A   ArangoUtils.py
A   Initalisation.py
M   README.md
A   Tests.py
M   __init__.py
A   requeriments.txt
A   testUtils.py
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
CONFLICT (modify/delete): __init__.py deleted in geth and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of __init__.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (modify/delete): README.md deleted in geth and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of README.md left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): requeriments.txt deleted in geth and renamed to PoM/requeriments.txt in HEAD. Version HEAD of PoM/requeriments.txt left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): Tests.py deleted in geth and renamed to PoM/Tests.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of PoM/Tests.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): Initalisation.py deleted in geth and renamed to PoM/Initalisation.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of PoM/Initalisation.py left in tree.    
CONFLICT (rename/delete): ArangoUtils.py deleted in geth and renamed to PoM/ArangoUtils.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of PoM/ArangoUtils.py left in tree.
CONFLICT (rename/delete): testUtils.py deleted in geth and renamed to Django/__init__.py in HEAD. Version HEAD of Django/__init__.py left in tree.
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0003 geth
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

What would it mean to skip the patch or check out the original branch? What would I want to do?

```
$ git status
rebase in progress; onto 8dc5f38
You are currently rebasing.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   ArangoUtils.py

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
    added by us:     PoM/ArangoUtils.py
    added by us:     PoM/EdgeEnum.py
    added by us:     PoM/Initalisation.py
    added by us:     PoM/Tests.py
    added by us:     PoM/requeriments.txt
    deleted by them: README.md
    deleted by them: __init__.py

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   PoM/ArangoUtils.py
```

I wanted to see what happens if I checkout the last commit to see if I can redo the whole rebase, but this won't happen either:

```
$ git checkout 70dd5f98f83a30285b05849917ebde598b59907e
PoM/ArangoUtils.py: needs merge
PoM/EdgeEnum.py: needs merge
PoM/Initalisation.py: needs merge
PoM/Tests.py: needs merge
PoM/requeriments.txt: needs merge
README.md: needs merge
__init__.py: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

I went along with the tutorial here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56597484/2516892

```
cd A
git remote add second https://second.repo

git fetch second
git checkout second/master
git checkout -b second

git rebase master second
```

Which did the job, but now I'm struggling how to properly merge.

Comment: You're using an older version of Git, in which `git rebase` uses the "am" (Apply Mailbox) back-end. This kind of rebase does not deal with file renames very well (more precisely, it doesn't *try*). Using `git rebase -m` instead of `git rebase` will direct your Git to use the "merge" back-end, which does handle renames. That might not actually fix anything, but given the apparent renames, it's certainly worth a try.

Comment: Note that `git rebase` was changed to use the newer back-end by default in Git 2.26, so if you upgrade to that version or later, you won't need to remember to use `-m`.

Comment: @torek - I updated, but I'm just getting different messages. `git rebase -m
fatal: It seems that there is already a rebase-apply directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.`. Also tried the `mergetool`, but it wouldn't resolve anything. Except I have a lot of *.orig Files now

Comment: You'll need to abort the in-progress rebase before starting a new one. The `*.orig` files are left over from the in-progress rebase; `git rebase --abort` won't clean them up either, so you'll need to do that manually (e.g., `find . name \*.orig -delete`, though I prefer to `-print` the names to a /tmp file and check it carefully first, just in case.)